# How to make the Mercurial (hgwebdir) rss/atom feed display the branch name

Tags: mercurial, rss, atom-feed

I would like to configure our Mercurial server installation so the rss/atom feed will publish the branch name of the changeset, in addition to the standard fields (title, guid, description, author, pubDate).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a [solution](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.mercurial.general/23571/focus=23659) on [the Mercurial mailing lists](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MailingLists).

I had to edit **templates\rss-log\changelogentry.tmpl** like this:

```
<item>
  <title>{desc|strip|firstline|strip|escape}</title>
  <guid isPermaLink="true">{urlbase}{url}rev/{node|short}</guid>
  <description>
    <![CDATA[<i>{inbranch%branchname}{branches%branchname}</i>
    <p>{desc|strip|escape|addbreaks|nonempty}]]>
  </description>
  <files>{file_mods}</files>
  <author>{author|obfuscate}</author>
  <pubDate>{date|rfc822date}</pubDate>
</item>
```

And I had to add the following line to **templates\rss-log\map**:

```
branchname = '{name}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Installation locations differ, but on ubuntu you'll find the relevant file as `/usr/share/mercurial/templates/atom/changelogentry.tmpl`.

It starts out looking like:

```
 <entry>
  <title>{desc|strip|firstline|strip|escape|nonempty}</title>
  <id>{urlbase}{url}#changeset-{node}</id>
  <link href="{urlbase}{url}rev/{node|short}"/>
  <author>
   <name>{author|person|escape}</name>
   <email>{author|email|obfuscate}</email>
      </author>
  <updated>{date|rfc3339date}</updated>
  <published>{date|rfc3339date}</published>
  <content type="xhtml">
   <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <pre xml:space="preserve">{desc|escape|nonempty}</pre>
   </div>
  </content>
 </entry>
```

and you can add anything you find in `hg help templates` including:

```
branches    String. The name of the branch on which the changeset was committed. Will be
            empty if the branch name was default.
```